# What is the cause of this Syntax error

Tags: python

I'm wondering why my code doesn't work. Is it not a string? Are my periods affecting my code? Quotes somewhere?

```
def intro(name,school):
    return "Hello. My name is" + str(name). + "I go to" + str(school).
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Why do you feel the periods are necessary?

Answer (score 5):

You script returns a **syntax error** because you cannot add a full-stop to a string by `str(name).` but it too has to be added as a string `str(name) + "."`

```
def intro(name,school):
    return "Hello. My name is " + str(name) + "." + " I go to " + str(school) + "."

print intro('kevin','university of wisconsin')
```

This would print *(Notice the extra spaces I have added, `"I go to"` replaced with `" I go to "` so that the output is more readable)*:

> Hello. My name is kevin. I goto university of wisconsin.

But you can use the `format()` method to overcome the complexity of string additions:

```
def intro(name,school):
    return "Hello. My name is {0}. I goto {1}.".format(name,school)

print intro('kevin','university of wisconsin')
```

Output:

> Hello. My name is kevin. I goto university of wisconsin.

**Please Note :** as mentioned in a  comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18928748/2425215) you cannot use:

`print intro(kevin,university of wisconsin)` as it would bring a `Syntax Error`, *why?, because variables cannot have spaces and strings must have quotes or python thinks `kevin` as a variable* but your always welcome to do it like:

```
name = 'kevin'
school = 'university of wisconsin'

def intro(name,school):
    return "Hello. My name is " + str(name) + "." + " I go to " + str(school) + "."
    #return "Hello. My name is {0}. I goto {1}.".format(name,school)

print intro(name,school)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the interpreter..

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def intro(name,school): return "Hello. My name is" + str(name). + "I go to" + str(school).
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def intro(name,school): return "Hello. My name is" + str(name). + "I go to" + str(school).
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

It gives you a good clue that the syntax is wrong right around `str(name).`.  Sure enough, it is.  Same issue @ `str(school).` Change it to:

```
def intro(name,school): 
    return "Hello. My name is" + str(name) + ". I go to" + str(school) + "."
```

Comment: Hmm...I wanted to be able to put any name and school in the python shell and have it print it out. like intro(kevin,university of wisconsin) would spit out 'Hello. My name is kevin. I go to university of wisconsin'. Do I change the string for name and school into quotes and unquote the 'Hello my name is/I go to' part? I feel like I'm stabbing in the dark.

Comment: As the answer shows, you currently have a stray period `.` *outside* of the quotes, which needs to be *inside* the quotes.

Comment: One could also just use `str.format(...)`. `"Hello. My name is {0}. I go to {1}.".format(name, school)`.